# how to get or reflect the name of the bash function which is called?

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, variable, function

i did not yet found a solution to this. Anyone a hint?

i sometimes write bash functions in my shell scripts and i love to have my scripts being verbose, not just for debugging. so sometimes i would like to display the "name" of a called bash function as a "variable" in my scripts.

what i did sometimes is setting just a regular variable containing the function name. like this:

```
test ()
{
    funcName=test
    echo "function running..."
    echo "\$0 is : $0"
    echo "function name is : $funcName"
}
```

but that is kinda stupid.

Is there something better?

Comment: In this instance it's easy to find the dupe when you know the answer, it's hard to phrase the search to find the answer when you only know your question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it's enough to read `man bash`:

> FUNCNAME
>
> An array variable containing the names of all shell
>                 functions currently in the execution call stack.  The
>                 element with index 0 is the name of any
>                 currently-executing shell function.  The bottom-most
>                 element (the one with the highest index) is "main".
>                 This variable exists only when a shell function is
>                 executing.  Assignments to FUNC- NAME have no effect and
>                 return an error status.  If FUNCNAME is unset, it loses
>                 its special properties, even if it is subsequently
>                 reset.

Example usage:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

func()
{
    echo I am inside "$FUNCNAME"
}

foo()
{
    echo I am inside "$FUNCNAME"
}

func
foo
```

Comment: sometimes people do that and still do not find it.